# Data Transfer approach between Nifi Cluster

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I am looking for a reliable data transfer approach between different Nifi cluster.
I have two Nifi cluster - one fetching data from source and another for pushing data into Hive/HDFS.

I need to transfer data from first nifi cluster to another nifi cluster. Is there any component available in nifi to do this ?

Nifi Cluster 1
GetFile --> Publish to Port

Nifi Cluster 2
Read from Port --> Publish to HDFS

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache NiFi provides the site-to-site feature for transferring data between two instances. You can read about it here:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#site-to-site

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I was referring to your post https://bryanbende.com/development/2016/08/30/apache-nifi-1.0.0-secure-site-to-site

Does input port in Nifi 2 cluster required to be at root level of nifi canvas ? can it be part of any process group ?

Comment: Currently site-to-site can only interact with ports on the root canvas... the way to think about it is that ports in general let you connect to something outside the current group, so when you are inside a process group it connects to the process group, so when you are on the root group it connects outside the instance

Comment: Got it..and I am hoping you can define Nifi policies for restricting access to canvas input port. Only authorised user will be able to post any data on that port.

Comment: Yes, should be shown in that post, there is a global policy for who can retrieve site-to-site details for the cluster, and then a per-port policy for who can push/pull to/from that port